# Can't delete row from UITableView (Delete button never appears)

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4.2

I'm trying to delete a row using Xcode 4.2 and a storyboard. The Table is nested in a `UINavigationController` nested in a `UITabBarController`.

My `UITableViewDelegate` class implements the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCellEditingStyle result = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

    if ([tableView isEqual:self.tableView]==YES) {
        result = UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
        NSLog(@"hi");
    }

    return result;
}
```

and when I swipe a row, I see the `"hi"` message in the log, but the row never receives a "Delete" button. Looking at sources like http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1, my

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"hi2");
}
```

method is never called.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if method `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` returns `YES` for appropriate index paths.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. Always seems to be one little detail missing. :)